# What is commonly known as 'love'?

Tags: love

Love is a common topic in literature, drama and music. People talk about loving people, being 'in love', falling out of love etc.

I think often in common usage people aren't necessarily referring to the same thing, and often people say 'You have to have been in love to know what it is'.

My question is - is the topic of 'love' studied in cognitive sciences - and if so, what is it?